# opendaylight: Genius install flow in switch

Tags: openflow, opendaylight, genius-api

I am using opendaylight / Carbon and am trying to work with the Genius wrapper. I want to install a flow in a switch based on a MAC address match for an incoming packet. The instruction I want to install is a "GOTO" instruction. I proceed as follows:

```
     FlowEntityBuilder flowEntityBuilder = new FlowEntityBuilder();
    flowEntityBuilder.setTableId(tableId)
        .setDpnId(dpnId)
        .setFlowId(FlowUtils.createFlowId().toString())
        .setFlowName("gotoTable1");

    MatchInfo matchInfo = new MatchEthernetSource(macAddress);


    InstructionInfo instructionInfo = new InstructionGotoTable(tableId);
    FlowEntity flowEntity = flowEntityBuilder.addInstructionInfoList(instructionInfo).addMatchInfoList(matchInfo).build();
    mdsalApiManager.installFlow(dpnId,flowEntity);
```

Mu intention was to create a flow entity and install it using the IMDSalApiManager.installFlow method.

Here is the exception that I see:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Node (urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)ethernet-source is missing mandatory descendant /(urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory?revision=2013-08-19)address
```

Any help debugging this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you build a GOTO instruction with OpenDaylight :

```
GoToTableBuilder gttb = new GoToTableBuilder();
gttb.setTableId(tableGoto);

Instruction gotoInstruction = new InstructionBuilder()
    .setOrder(1).setInstruction(new GoToTableCaseBuilder()
        .setGoToTable(gttb.build())
        .build())
    .build();
```

You can use this to adjust your code.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue on my end where the MacAddress supplied was null. I fixed this problem. However I still do not see the flow in the switch.

Comment: What is the error in ovs log or else you can check what is the error by capturing packet transfer between your controller and ovs.

Comment: I had a null for Node and hence the error. I had to use an InstanceId<FlowCapableNode> to install the flow.